# Leaflet marker is not draggable even if draggable=true

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, leaflet

I'm using a Leaflet map with [markers](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker).

When the user clicks "edit" on my page, I want to make the markers draggable. If I set the property `draggable` to true for each marker, it doesn't work.

When I create a new marker and set the property right from the beginning, it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You gotta do it like this:

```
marker.dragging.disable(); // marker.dragging.enable();
```

My first attempt only changes a technical property but not [the behavior](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-dragging).

Comment: Thanks as well. I was wondering how to do this as I need such functionality as well! :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me now.  `TypeError: [marker].dragging is undefined`

Comment: @mc0e you have to add your marker to map first. `marker.addTo(map)`

Answer (score 2):

Motivated by @mc0e problem concerning 'undefined'. Here is an example.

(Based on the code from [Leafletjs.com](http://leafletjs.com/index.html) and [Leafletjs quick start](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/))

1. Open **[Wikimedia maps](https://maps.wikimedia.org)** (which is based on the framework in question).
2. Open browser console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) to put a Marker (you will need to define a variable first). Use Code-1.

**Code-1 in console:**

```
var markerLondon = L.marker()
    .setLatLng([51.5, -0.09])
    .bindPopup('Centre of London')
    .addTo(map)
    .openPopup();
```

3. Now you have a non-draggable marker. Use Code-2 to make the Marker draggable.

**Code-2 in console:**

```
markerLondon.dragging.enable();
```

---

Further reading: **[Marker API reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker)**.

PS: Once Wikimedia starts using something else, you may test it with [BigMap 2](http://bigmap.osmz.ru/) (also based on the same framework) created for making static OpenStreetMap images.